# How to init data when use jquery ui?

Tags: jquery-ui

I have one checkbox use jQuery UI

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_1" name="checkbox_1" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox_1" class="checked">checkbox_1</label>
<script>
$(function){
    $("input:checkbox").button();
};
</script>
```

And I query the data from database,the checkbox should be checked.
But it doesn't works when I added the attribute of "checked" in checkbox like normal usage.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in html
`<input type="checkbox"`**checked="checked"**`id="checkbox_1" name="checkbox_1" value="1" />`

Comment: Thank you~ I had only wtite like this <input checked type="checkbox"/>  Now it works!